# JavaFX : Access to A Component From Another Class

Tags: java, javafx-2

I've a webserver in my application that wants to get an input from a textField then write it's answer into that,then disable the textField Editable property.

I do something like this in my Controller Class:

```
@FXML
public static TextField empty_box;
```

but it gives me this error:

> javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
>   /C:/....../View/WorkSpace.fxml

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at Parking.View.ParkingLoginController.auth(ParkingLoginController.java:210)
at Parking.View.ParkingLoginController.login(ParkingLoginController.java:113)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I know that making the TextField Variable into public static is cause of the error,wanna know in this situation what would be the alternative or correct approach.

Thanks

Comment: Why not expose the component using a getter?

Comment: @AustinD
Is there any better approach?